# TextView background does not wrap content

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a TextView inside ConstraintLayout with a background drawable.
It's width is set to 0dp `(match_constraint)`. If I set it to `wrap_content`, the text clips at the end.

I want the background to be the size of `TextView` only.

[image: This is how I'm getting it]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_receive"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_chat_message"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is a received message"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After setting it to `wrap_content`:

[image]

**Edit:**

`rounded_chat_message.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the `TextView` from clipping when using `wrap_content` to need to set the `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` attribute. This will enforce the horizontal constraints when the width is set to `wrap_content` so both `start` and `end` have to be set (which they are in your case). Now to make the `TextView` stick to the start you need to set `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"` (or `1` to align to the end).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_receive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_chat_message"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="Message"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules you use make the view stretch to the end of your parent.
Remove this line from the TextView XML definition, and it should look fine:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: I had tried that, but when the text gets long it just sticks to the right side

Comment: Check my edit, to see how it looks after `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Put this properties.

```
<TextView
    ...
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="This is a received "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextView inside some other layout and align that TextView to start of it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_receive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ded"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.
        Light.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        tools:text="This is a received message" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I already tried this in my editor and this is working as per your requirements

Comment: if you put other layout in constraint layout then why to use constraintlayout itself

Comment: if you use constraint layout that doesn't mean you are not allowed to use other layouts. the only purpose of constraint layout to avoid nested layouts in case complex layouts.